# Maven build for mspnp/spark-monitoring project using scala-2.12_spark-3.4.1 Errors

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to send Azure Databricks logs to a Log Analytics Workspace, and using the open source spark-monitoring solution to do it (https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring).

Upon adding a profile for scala-2.12_spark-3.4.1 to my pom.xml to support the Maven build, and executing the build, it keeps erroring with the following error:

```
spark-monitoring-main/src/spark-listeners/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/listeners/UnifiedSparkListener.scala:69: value sparkEventToJson is not a member of object org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.8.1:compile (default) on project spark-listeners: Execution default of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:4.8.1:compile failed: Compilation failed: InterfaceCompileFailed
```

I have tried downgrading to use older versions of spark, but it keeps erroring out during the build with the same error above.

Anyone ran into this or know anything about what this error is pertaining to? I posted the issue on the GitHub project but it's crickets. TIA